# How do I stop my program from reading the second while loop when not needed?

Tags: python

I have some homework which I'm not sure how to finish.

The task given was to make a script which would ask the user to enter his name, after entering it, the script would check if the name entered matches with any of the names on a pre-existing list.

If the name matches the script would ask the user if they would like to delete the name off the list or keep it.

If the name doesn't match with any names on the list, it asks if the user if they'd like to add it on it.

The script should write the list of names in the end.

I wrote it like this:

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
lk = ['Peti','John','Mary','Claire','Hellen']
while name in lk:
    print("Your name is already in our list.")
    if name in lk:
       bris = input("Would you like to delete your name off our list?[Y/N]:")
    if bris == "Y":
            lk.remove(name)
            print("Your name was removed.")
            print(lk)
            break
    elif bris == "N":
            print("OK!",name,"Your name will be saved.")
            print(lk)
            break
while name not in lk:
        doda = input("Your name is not registered on our list, would you like to add it?[Y/N]:")
        if doda == "Y":
            lk.append(name)
            print("Your name has been added.")
            print(lk)
        elif doda == "N":
            print("Alright, goodbye",name,"!")
            break
```

Issue is, that I have no idea how to stop it once the user chooses to delete their name off the list, it always reads the next while because the deleted name is no longer on the list.

Also, I am very sorry if this looks like poo poo I'm new to coding

Comment: Hi, you have to ask the user name one time or repeatedly?

Comment: Hello, the user name needs to be entered only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user needs to be entered only once, why using loop?

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
lk = ['Peti','John','Mary','Claire','Hellen']
if name in lk:
    print("Your name is already in our list.")
    
    bris = input("Would you like to delete your name off our list?[Y/N]:")
    if bris == "Y":
            lk.remove(name)
            print("Your name was removed.")
            print(lk)
    elif bris == "N":
            print("OK!",name,"Your name will be saved.")
            print(lk)

else:
    doda = input("Your name is not registered on our list, would you like to add it?[Y/N]:")
    if doda == "Y":
        lk.append(name)
        print("Your name has been added.")
        print(lk)
    elif doda == "N":
        print("Alright, goodbye",name,"!")
```

Comment: I didn't really understand what it did, so I used it wrong. Thank you for your reply, I fixed it now and it works how I wanted it to! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop structure is the root of the issue. Since you're using `while` loops I'm assuming you want your script to loop and keep asking for new inputs. In this case you'll want one loop that you can break out of when you're done entering names based on some user input:

```py
lk = ['Peti','John','Mary','Claire','Hellen']

while keep_looping = 'Y':
    # check a name
    name = input("Please enter a name: ")

    if name in lk:
        # name in list logic here
    else:
        # name not in list logic here

    # ask user if the loop should continue. Entering 'N' will break the loop
    keep_looping = input("Would you like to try another name? (Y/N): ")
```

You can reuse your existing logic for checking for names in the list and adding/removing, but you'll also want the name checking logic as an if/else block so only one condition can be met per loop. Otherwise you'll run into the same issue when a name exists and gets removed.

There are other optimizations you can do but I'll let you figure those out on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I figured out my issue, I used the while loop for no reason. I used it without knowing what exactly it did. Thank you for helping either way!

Answer (score 0):

name = input("Please enter your name:")

lk = ['Peti','John','Mary','Claire','Hellen']

if name in lk:

```
print("your name already present in list")

k= input(("would you like to delete your name from the list: [y/n]:"))

if k=="y":

    lk.remove(name)

    print("your name is deleted from the list")

    print(lk)
else:

    print("your name kept as it is in the list")
```

else:

```
print("your name is not present in list")

k= input(("would you like to add your name to the list: [y/n]:"))

if k=="y":

    lk.append(name)

    print("your name is added to the list")

    print(lk)

else:

    print("list is kept as it is")

    print(lk)
```

Comment: if you are checking name in the list then you don't have to use while you can directly check the name in the list then you can use if-else condition to add or delete name from the list